# Getting a "sub-polytope" of a concave d-dimensional polytope, given some one dimensional inequality

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-algebra

The question will be hard to understand without an example, so let's given an example first:
Let's say I have a 2 dimensional concave polytope, defined by a **circular sequence** of its vertices:

$(0,0),
(1, 4),
(2, 0)
(1, 1),
(0, 0)$
[image: The concave polytope]

Let's say I wanted to find the polytope I get if I considered only points s.t. $y>=0.5$, which means:
[image: The new concave polytope]

In this example, we would get the polytope with vertices:

$(0.125, 0.5),
(1, 4),
(1.875, 0.5),
(1.5, 0.5),
(1, 1),
(0.5, 0.5),
(0.125, 0.5)
$

What would be the way to do this computationally?
Generally, for $d$ dimensions, given a $d$ dimensional concave polytope defined by a **circular sequence** of its vertices (s.t. if I were to "travel" along the sequence of vertices, I'd get on every single edge of the polytope, and end where I started), and given an equation $x_i >= c$ for some constant c and for $i \in [0, d - 1]$, where $x_i$ is the coordinate, what would be the way to return a concave polytope which is defined by "cutting" the given polytope in the way I described in my example?

Answer (score 0):

When $d>2$, I believe a sequence of vertices does not uniquely determine a non-convex polytope, so it looks to me like your representation has some issues and your 2D example is misleading.

But assuming an appropriate representation of a (non-convex) polytope: If $d$ is not too large, the following works: Enumerate all the faces.  For each face, if it intersects with the plane $x_i=c$, then intersect the face with $x_i\ge c$ (and discard everything with $x_i<c$), and add vertices for each intersection with the plane $x_i=c$ that is on the perimeter of that face, and discard any vertices for which $x_i<c$.

Comment: How do I find all intersections of $x_i = c$ with the face?

Comment: @RonMichal, that depends on how you represent a face.  A natural way is a set of linear equalities/inequalities, and if so, then you can plug in $x_i=c$ into those linear equations and simplify. I suggest you spend some time thinking about it, then if you still are having difficulty, ask a new question, and specify the representation you are using.

Comment: Will definitely do. Is it possible to represent a facet with equalities/inequalities? How is a non-convex facet represented using equalities / inequalities?